# ADD or COPY actions not using cache when copying a git submodule folder during docker re-build

Tags: git, docker, dockerfile

<s>Docker is not caching the COPY/ADD actions and executes these layers at every re-build...</s>

I am using docker to setup the dev environment for a project that depends on specific commits of different projects. For this reason I have setup these projects as git submodules. The folder structure looks like this:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── llvm-project # a submodule folder pointing to a specific commit
│   └── ...
└── my-project   # a submodule folder pointing to a specific commit
    └── ...
```

During docker image creation I have the following lines in the `Dockerfile`:

```
COPY ./llvm-project /working_dir/llvm-project
COPY ./my-project /working_dir/my-project

RUN mkdir -p /builds/llvm-project /installs/llvm-project && \
    /working_dir/soda-opt/build_tools/./build_llvm.sh

RUN mkdir -p /builds/my-project && \
    /working_dir/my-project/build_tools/./build_my-project.sh
```

But every time I re-run docker build, the COPY/ADD actions run again, *even if the submodule folders did not have any file change*.

How can I make sure I use the cache for these copy actions?
Should I be copying these submodules using a different approach (`git clone`)?

UPDATE

@AntonioPetricca suggested me to look into the docker log. There I see that the COPY action is using the cache.

```
Step 12/18 : COPY ./llvm-project /working_dir/llvm-project
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 56de8bf88d85
```

It is just taking a long time because the `llvm-project` is a big folder with lots of files.

Should I include these submodules folders in a different way?

Comment: Could you post the docker build log?

Comment: Ah! @AntonioPetricca, thank you for the suggestion. It turns out that the cache is being used. Just taking long to calculate. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

In order to reduce the adding time I suggest you to create a `.dockerignore` file and add inside it the folder `.git/`.

So the calculation for cache matching will take less time if the git folder was not added.

Comment: After re-building this image a couple of times, it happens that the COPY layer is reused, but the "compilation of llvm-project" layer sometimes is is not... I have not modified anything in the submodules. Does changing the docker context (adding other files to the project elsewhere) may re-trigger this compilation? Cannot pinpoint the "why" yet. Maybe I modified something prior on the dockerfile without realizing... Curious if you have any insight.